# Proof $\pi$ is transcendental without symmetric function theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

Recently for a bonus homework assignment in my algebra class, I was asked to review the literature and write up a proof that $\pi$ is transcendental. Essentially every source I found ("The Transcendence of $\pi$" by Steve Mayer for example) presents the classic proof of Lindemann, which heavily relies on symmetric function theory and in particular the fundamental theorem of elementary symmetric functions.

Before this assignment, I did not know symmetric function theory, and by far the biggest difficulty in my solution and write up was understanding this theory and the argument used in the proof (which in my opinion, was not spelled out enough for a beginner to the theory to easily understand the argument in the sources I consulted).

Now, symmetric function theory was useful to learn, and I am aware it is very useful in the proof of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem, but it begs the question: Is there any proof (preferably understandable to approximately a beginning graduate student) that $\pi$ is transcendental, without using symmetric function theory, and if not, is there a theoretical explanation for why?

Edit: Crossposted to MO after 2.5 weeks https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466288/proof-pi-is-transcendental-without-symmetric-function-theory

Comment: The one method I know involves an improper integral…

Comment: How about $\displaystyle e^{i\pi}+1=0$, since $e$ is transcendental also $\pi$ must be transcendental. (But that only works if the proof for $e$ to be transcendental was before the one for $\pi$ -- I'm not good in history.)

Comment: @m-stgt The *result* that $~e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)~$ is artificial.  That is, I don't think that it can be derived, because the notion of a real (positive) number taken to an imaginary power can be reasonably regarded as gibberish, when compared to the idea of a real (positive) number taken to a real power.  The definition can be justified as allowing consistent results, but I don't see how you can use such a **definition** to **prove** that $~\pi~$ is transcendental.  Note that I am speaking out of intuition, rather than a formal education, so I may well be mistaken here.

Comment: @user2661923 -- I'm sure you may judge your intuition yourself if you regard $\displaystyle e^{i\pi}$ as _gibberish_ while Euler (and few others) take it for real. BTW, proof of $\pi$ to be transcendental was 1882, that for $e$ was 1873. So my suggestion is not circular.

Comment: @m-stgt My understanding, which could be mistaken is that Euler compared the Taylor Series of $~e^{i\theta}~$ with the Taylor series of $~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).~$  Assuming so, this is cart before the horse, because you must first attach some meaning to the idea of $~e~$ taken to an imaginary power.  Also, I wasn't suggesting that your logic was circular.  Instead, I was suggesting (perhaps wrongly) that nothing can be deduced as a consequence of an artificial definition, such as $~e^{i\theta}.$

Comment: @user2661923 -- to be honest, I myself **do not know** to "spell out" the reasoning, why the _"most bueauiful euqation"_ evidences $\pi$ to be transcendental -- I'm obliged to **believe** it. That, despite this, I bring this option to the table is only from memory, w/o reference at the moment. The hint about _not circular_ was only a post scriptum to my first comment, it has nothing to do with you.

Comment: Ok, my suggestion using $\displaystyle e^{i\pi}+1=0$ is **no answer** to the question in OP. Why? A _little_ digging in the Interrnet shows, this proof **is** from Lindemann (or based on it). Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: @user2661923 Defining $e^z$ for complex $z$ as a Taylor series is not "artificial", it's a very natural generalization from the real case. And once that's done, $e^{i\pi} = \sum \frac{(i\pi)^n}{n!}$ doesn't look like gibberish to me.

Comment: To settle this, the problem is not in the definition of the complex exponential, but rather (roughly as m-stgt points out) that the proof that goes: $e$ is transcendental, therefore $e^{i\pi}$ is algebraic only if $i\pi$ is transcendental, is essentially the entire fact to be proven (or a stronger form of it like Lindemann-Weierstrass).

Comment: You should understand the need of symmetric function theory here. It is needed to ensure that certain polynomial used in the proof has integer coefficients (this also applies for derivatives of the polynomial). There may be an alternative in Galois theory but I guess that is even more complicated compared to symmetric function theory.

Comment: Most irrationality/transcendence proofs use an expression which is a non-zero integer and hence has absolute value greater than or equal to $1$ and the same expression can be shown to be arbitrarily small in absolute value thereby giving a contradiction. Proving the expression to be a non-zero integer is where one needs the coefficients of the polynomial referred in previous comment.

Comment: I disagree with the implication that "$e$ is transcendental, therefore $e^{i\pi}$ is algebraic only if $i\pi$ is transcendental". Indeed, let $a\not\in\{0,1\}$ and $b\not\in\mathbb Q$ be any algebraic numbers.
Then, by Gelfond–Schneider theorem, answering [Hilbert's seventh problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventh_problem), $a^b$ is transcendental.
But the numbers $1/b$ and $(a^b)^{1/b}=a$ are algebraic.

Comment: @AlexRavsky -- Please consider the wording of 2nd point in [Hilbert's seventh problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventh_problem#Statement_of_the_problem), where $a$ is defined to be _algebraic_. In contrast, as we all know, $e$ is _not algebraic_. In addition, $\displaystyle (a^b)^\frac{1}{b}=a$ is as reverse function inapt as general proof.

Comment: @m-stgt The provided counterexample shows that the implication "if $x$ is transcendental and $x^y$ is algebraic then $y$ is transcendental" fails in general. So why if $e$ is transcendental and $e^{i\pi}$ is algebraic then $i\pi$ is transcendental?

Comment: @AlexRavsky -- I'm not convinced by your _"fails in general"_. For Lindemann (maybe few others too) it did not fail. Thus your question about the _why_ is answered in his papers, perhaps sufficiently. If you doubt, take your chance. BTW, not only $i\pi$, already $\pi$ on its own is transcendental.